# Set the canonical link rel via theme's template.php for a specific views page (not a node)

Tags: views, meta-tags

I do not want to use the D7 Metatag or the MetaTag Quick modules. How can I specify a single canonical link rel for a single URL which is not a node (a view page) via the theme's template.php?

I've tried this but it has a syntax error:

```
if (isset($_GET['q']) && preg_match("/^products\category/", $_GET['q']) {
  drupal_add_html_head(array(
    "#tag" => "link",
    "#attributes" => array(
      "rel" => "canonical",
      "href" => "https://domain.com/products/category",
    ),
  ), 'link_rel_canonical');
}
```

Comment: If it's a syntax error, then this question is not specific to Drupal and doesn't belong on this site. Also, you should be able to see what syntax error this is and fix it using common tools, like error reporting in the page or server logs. Jaypan already pointed out the missing closing bracket for the if condition.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not a developer but a website owner attempting on my own

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have a syntax error. You should be able to use this:

```php
if (preg_match("/^products\/category/", $_GET['q'])) {
  drupal_add_html_head(array(
    "#tag" => "link",
    "#attributes" => array(
      "rel" => "canonical",
      "href" => "https://domain.com/products/category",
    ),
  )), 'link_rel_canonical');
}
```

Comment: That did not work. The website white-screened and the editor says there is a syntax error on this line :  )), 'link_rel_canonical');

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, Jaypan. It worked by after I changed ```)), 'link_rel_canonical');``` to ``` ), 'link_rel_canonical');```